# Push staged items

Tags: git

Changes are committed with `git commit -m "commit message"`

When I execute command `git status` I have one file not committed:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   AAA/AX.cpp
```

I execute `git push` and expect to commit change. But I have answer:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

How to push changes then?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Comment: *"I execute git push and expect to commit change"* - if you want to commit then prepare the commit ([add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) files to index) then [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is a different thing. It sends the commits to a remote repository.

Comment: status shows that I have one item staged. That means I can push it?

Comment: @vico The status you posted above doesn't show any staged commits. It's unclear now if you didn't provide the full status message to begin with or if you used one of the below answers to commit changes (please accept one of them if that's the case) and that that is why your status shows something else now.

Comment: Did you do `git add -- AAA/AX.cpp` before `git commit` command ?

Answer (score 1):

`git commit -m "commit message"` would do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git commit` command to commit changes and then use `git push`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on a new machine.

As I had run a `git add -A` to add all the changes then `git commit -m "my commit"` I thought everything was ready to go, but I got the *Everything up-to-date* message.

Running `git commit` on its own showed an error

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

running those two commands and setting my identity then allowed me to run the commit again and then

```
git status
```

showed

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

then
`git push` worked as expected

really caught me out because I have used only one machine to do commits prior and had at some point setup my identity.